# How do I get a dropdown menu that uses hover to work on touchscreen?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is [my website](https://ignitefitness.github.io/ignitefitness_project.github.io/index.html) for a school project, it is designed to be viewed on a phone. I have a dropdown menu on it near the top that uses hover, which does not work on touch devices. I need to make this work with clicking (I don't really care if hover still works, I need to click) but do not know how. How do I make this work with tapping on a touchscreen? I really want to stay away from javascript for now and just use HTML and CSS. I am very new to webdesign so I will need a very basic explanation. Also I know my images take a long time to load, any suggestions on how to address that would also be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most touch devices *lack* the ability to provoke a true hover interaction (some exceptions would be the Samsung Galaxy Note with pen, Microsoft Surface devices with pen, and the iPad Pro with pen).

That said, touching an element that has a `:hover` pseudo selector with associated styles (as you do) should invoke that hover event, even in mobile browsers on touch devices.

Have you viewed your website on a touch device? The menu appears as expected with tapping on my Google Pixel (with Chromium browser) as well as on my Surface device in tablet mode.

There may be some browsers/devices or combinations thereof that do not exhibit this behavior, but I believe it's quite standard.

---

If you need a more principled solution, I'd suggest making the nav toggle a `<button>` element and executing some basic JavaScript on `click` events. I realize you don't want to stray into that territory right now, but that's exactly the sort of use case at which JavaScript excels.

---

If you really want to avoid JavaScript *and* you don't like relying on the touch-invokes-hover-event approach, there's always the checkbox hack. As the name indicates, it's a hack. I wouldn't recommend it for your particular use case. But to each his/her own.

[Here's](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) a CSS Tricks article on all the interesting uses the checkbox hack can be applied to.